# How to realize RenderPartial of UserControl in Classic ASP.NET and send serialized result to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Classic ASP.NET there is LoadControl method. But if I create base class of UserControl in the same way

```
public class RenderingControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string GetHtml(Type ControlType, int id1)
    {
        var page = new Page();
        var control = page.LoadControl(ControlType, new object[] { id1 });
        page.Controls.Add(control);
        return RenderControlToHtml(control);
    }

    string RenderControlToHtml(Control control)
    {
        var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        control.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb1)));
        return sb1.ToString();
    }
}
```

(all my controls derived from base class with additional method GetHtml)

```
public partial class FilterStatus : RenderingControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And than try to send this Control to Browser in the same way

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public string Filters(string type, int id) {
        var X = new FilterStatus();
        return X.GetHtml(X.GetType(), id);
    }
```

I receive in Browser full page with needed control. This is wrong in my project logic. I need receive ONLY my UserControl (like working RenderPartial in ASP.NET MVC). How to do this in Classic ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

RenderPartial is not related to ASP.NET. Because ASP.NET is a conveyor of special events, like PageLoad. I have realized RenderPartial as simplest text processor

```
public class GetControl : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        try
        {
            string Fname = "";
            string Base = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Filters");
            switch (context.Request.QueryString["Filter"])
            {
                case "Status": Fname = "FilterStatus.htm"; break;
                ...
                default: return;
            }

            string HTML = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Base, Fname));
            context.Response.Write(HTML.Replace("@", context.Request.QueryString["Id"]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]